# How to check in MATLAB if a vector only contains zeros?

Tags: matlab

What is the "MATLAB-way" to check if a vector only contains zeros, so that it will be evaluated to a scalar rather than to a vector. If I run this code:

```
vector = zeros(1,10)

%the "1" represents a function that returns a scalar
if 1 && vector == 0   %this comparision won't work
    'success'
end
```

I get the error:

> ??? Operands to the || and &&
>   operators must be convertible to
>   logical scalar values.

Comment: The error you're getting is because you're using the `&&` operator between a scalar and a vector. For comparing vectors of equal size, use the `&` operator to get a logical array. Otherwise, you must use another function such as `any` or `all` to reduce your vector to a single scalar.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `all`:

```
vector = zeros(1,10)
if 1 && all(vector == 0)   %this comparision will work
    'success'
end
```

Comment: It should be noted that you don't need the `1 &&`. It serves no purpose.

Comment: @gnovice: I don't actually have `1` there, but a function that returns a scalar.

Comment: @Lucas: Oh, OK. That makes sense now. I would have put a place holder in the code like `some_fcn(...) && ` to make it a little clearer, though.

Comment: @gnovice: You are right. I edited my question, but don't want to remove the `1` or the answers will seem weird. If I don't have a logical operand though, the problem doesn't exist.

Answer (score 15):

Since zeros are treated the same way as `false`, you don't need to use `vector == 0`, as [ptomato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2873768/1714410) suggests.  `~any(vector)` is the "MATLAB-way" to check for only zero values.

```
if 1 && ~any(vector)   
    'success'
end
```

Extending the problem to arrays, you'd have to use

```
array = zeros(5);
if 1 && ~any(array(:))
    'success'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but how about `nnz` ([Number of Non-Zeros](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html))?

```
if 1 && nnz(vector)==0
    'success'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find out if any and how many entries in `vector` contain non-zero elements using the following:

```
vector = zeros(1, 10); 
nrNonZero = sum(vector~=0)
```

`vector~=0` returns an array of the same dimensions as `vector` containing zeros and ones, representing true and false, for the given statement. The variable `nrNonZero` then contains the number of non-zero elements in `vector`.

So, your code would then be

```
if (sum(vector~=0) == 0)
    'success'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using this:

```
if(boolFunCall() & ~vector)
    disp('True');  
else
    disp('False');
end
```

Just as Doresoom stated, your problem is in the use of `&&` instead of `&`.  Also, the `~` inverts all of the 1's and 0's thereby making a zero vector into a vector of 1's:

```
test = [0 0 0 0 0 0];
~test
ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
test = [1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0];
~test
ans =

     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     1
```